# Comparar una variable con una consulta SQLite3

Tags: python, sql, base-de-datos, sqlite3

Quiero hacer un log in y comparar si existe el usuario, pero al momento de hacer la consulta me devuelve el valor como una tupla y marca error aunque si exista el usuario. dejo la foto de la base de datos de la que quiero hacer la consulta

```
import sqlite3


mail = "ivan@gmail.com"
pwd = "Hola123"

#CONEXION
class Base_datos():


    def buscar(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("tattoRecognizer.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        
        cursor.execute("SELECT Correo FROM Usuario")
        for linea in cursor:
            if mail == linea:
                resultado = 1
                break
                
            else:
                resultado = 0

        return resultado

#instancia
query = Base_datos()
resultado = query.buscar()
print(f"El resultado de la funcion es: {resultado}")
```

Comment: Sería interesando ver que contiene `linea` para ver que está comparando ...

Answer (score 1):

#### Explicación

Cuando haces una consulta sql, y iteras sobre el cursor, lo que devuelve es un iterador que va devolviendo tuplas (inclusive si solo estás consultando una sola columna).

Cuando iteras sobre esa lista, vas obteniendo tuplas de un solo item.

Ejemplo:

Teniendo esta tabla

| columna1 | columna2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

Y haciendo

```
SELECT columna2 FROM tabla
```

Irás obteniendo estas tuplas:

```
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
```

Y si comparas una tupla con algo que no es una tupla (como una cadena) siempre dará False: `1 == (1,)`

#### Solución siguiendo tu código

Desempaqueta la tupla. Esto podés hacerlo, por ejemplo, usando el [desempaquetado](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp)

```
import sqlite3


mail = "ivan@gmail.com"
pwd = "Hola123"

#CONEXION
class Base_datos():


    def buscar(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("tattoRecognizer.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        
        cursor.execute("SELECT Correo FROM Usuario")
        for (linea,) in cursor:
            if mail == linea:
                resultado = 1
                break
                
            else:
                resultado = 0

        return resultado

#instancia
query = Base_datos()
resultado = query.buscar()
print(f"El resultado de la funcion es: {resultado}")
```

#### La Mejor Solución

En realidad, lo que estás haciendo, debería hacerse desde la base de datos.

Tu enfoque de que el cliente revise todos los registros tiene desventajas:

- Se carga todos los datos en memoria.
- Es mucho más lento.
- No estoy seguro de esto ultimo. Pero lo mencionaré igual. Le estás dando al cliente todos los datos de todos los usuarios. Sospecho que si accedes a la lista en memoria con algún programa, tendrá acceso a todos los usuarios de la base de datos.

Entonces, lo mejor es que uses la función exists, la clausula where y pasar parametros a la consulta.

```
# los signos de pregunta y la tupla pasada de segundo argumento
# a execute, son los parametros
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT Null FROM usuario WHERE Correo=? AND password=?", (mail, pwd))
```

Esta consulta devuelve siempre una sola fila y una sola columna. Si existe al menos un registro con el correo y la constraseña pasadas, el unico valor que hay será True. De lo contrario False.

Como es una sola fila, nos alcanza con obtener dicha fila con cursor.fetchone(). Y como siempre será una sola columna, la desempaquetamos:

```
(is_valid_user,) = cursor.fetchone()
```

**Codigo Completo**

```
import sqlite3


mail = "ivan@gmail.com"
pwd = "Hola123"

#CONEXION
class Base_datos():


    def buscar(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("tattoRecognizer.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        
        cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT Null FROM usuario WHERE Correo=? AND password=?", (mail, pwd))
        (resultado,) = cursor.fetchone()

        return resultado

#instancia
query = Base_datos()
resultado = query.buscar()
print(f"El resultado de la funcion es: {resultado}")
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que línea es una tupla con todas las columnas que pediste en el `SELECT`. No importa que sea 1 o muchas columnas, siempre será una tupla. Entonces comparar tupla vs cadena siempre dará `False`. Para resolver eso, solo basta con:

```py
if mail == linea[0]:
```

Pero hay más problemas, que pueden ser tomados como "basados en opiniones", pero los expondré para que los tengas en cuenta.
(2) No estás dejando que la base de datos haga su trabajo, por lo tanto ese `for` está de más.
(3) La conexión a la base de datos la manejas de forma local en un método, esto no tiene mucho sentido si estás trabajando con clases.

```py
import sqlite3

#CONEXION
class Base_datos():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def get_db_cursor(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("tattoRecognizer.db")
        return conexion.cursor()
    
    def buscar(self, email, clave):
        cursor = self.get_db_cursor()
        query = "SELECT Correo, Contra FROM Usuario WHERE Correo=?"
        #                         ^--- Nombre de columna de la clave
        res = cursor.execute(query, (email,))
        fila = res.fetchone()
        if fila and fila[1] == clave:
            resultado = 1 # Usuario y contraseña correctos
        else:
            resultado = 0 # Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos
        return resultado
        
mail = "ivan@gmail.com"
pwd = "Hola123"
#instancia
query = Base_datos()
resultado = query.buscar(mail, pwd)
print(f"El resultado de la funcion es: {resultado}")
```

Comment: Sobre el punto 3, hay algunos que abren la conexión, hacen la consulta y luego la cierran. Una vez le pregunté a alguien por que lo hacen y parece que es por seguridad. Pero a mi me cuesta creer que eso funcione bien como algo de seguridad. Pero el punto es que podría ser intencional lo de abrir la conexion.

Comment: Si, @DanteS. no tiene mucho sentido en seguridad, de hecho, es usual que la parte de base de datos sea manejada y heredada desde otra clase. Si el script ejecuta y se cierra, creo que no hay problema. Abrir y cerrar muchas conexiones parece tiene [repercusiones en rendimiento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829115/1545868). Si el script permanece abierto o monitoreando, entonces si se puede cerrar la conexión mientras no sea necesario usar la BD. Todo depende del desarrollo. Conviene mantener centralizada esta parte, modifiqué un poco el código para hacerlo más privadamente.